# Adding "Internal keywords" in Experiance Profile of Sitecore 8 Analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics

I need help. How can I add **"Internal keywords"** in **Sitecore 8 Analytics** (Experiance Profile -> Activity -> Keywords)?
I tried to write keywords in code:

```
Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Keywords = query;
```

but in Experiance Profile I have not found anything!

[image]

Comment: How is this related to mongo?

Comment: It isn't, therefor I remove the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also encountered with this problem. I can wite **"Internal keywords"** in Experiance Profile of Sitecore 8 by the adding of "Search Page Event" (standart item - "/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Search") on my view page.

Code `"Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Keywords = query;"` is not used in my case.

### Example

```
string query = "Example keywords in field <Keywords>";
Guid searchPageEventGuid = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{0C179613-2073-41AB-992E-027D03D523BF}").ID.Guid;
Guid view4Guid = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{D0D0E48C-7DE0-4C95-A994-F5ED00DC9820}").ID.Guid;
var page = Tracker.Current.Interaction.CurrentPage;

page.Register(new PageEventData("My search page event data", searchPageEventGuid)
                {
                    ItemId = view4Guid,
                    Data = query,
                    DataKey = query,
                    Text = query,

                });
```

"view4Guid" - this is my custom view page

### Result:

1. **Search Page Event** is called after visit of view page - "view4"
   [image]
2. **Internal keywords** is vied in **keyword tab**
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Example with Search Page Event really works and code: `Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Keywords = query;` is not needed!